# Internal Tesing don't work when using Close Tesing

Tags: android, google-play

I have 2 groups A and group B.
First I published with internal testing for these 2 groups. Everything works fine.
Then I accidentally published the app with close testing. Right after I discovered this. I have deleted everything related to close testing.
However, when I return to publishing with 2 groups A and B in internal testing. The accounts assigned to those 2 groups cannot see the internal publication anymore.